# Don't want Oracle modulo in group by

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, modulo

When I make a select statement with several columns and a MOD, the MOD has to be in the GROUP BY but I don't want to :).

```
SELECT LOCATION, ROUND(MIN(TEM)) TN, MOD((to_number(TO_CHAR(DATE, 'hh24'))+RANGE), 24)
FROM TABLE
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND RANGE BETWEEN 18 AND 30
GROUP BY LOCATION, MOD((to_number(TO_CHAR(DATE, 'hh24'))+RANGE), 24)
ORDER BY LOCATION
```

I want by LOCATION: the LOCATION, the min value of TEM and the date.

So do you have an idea on how to do this query without the MOD in the GROUP BY ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Analytical Functions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION, TN, my_mod
FROM
(
SELECT LOCATION, MIN(TEM)) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION) TN, MOD((to_number(TO_CHAR(DATE, 'hh24'))+RANGE), 24) my_mod
FROM TABLE
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND RANGE BETWEEN 18 AND 30
)
order by location;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `group by`, use `row_number()` to identify the minimum value of `TEM` and then just finish the query from there:

```
SELECT LOCATION, ROUND(TEM) TN, MOD((to_number(TO_CHAR(DATE, 'hh24'))+RANGE), 24)
FROM (SELECT t.*, row_number over (partition by location order by tem) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE t
      WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND RANGE BETWEEN 18 AND 30
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY LOCATION
```